# maths.sin answer wrong in Java

Tags: java

I tried the code .The answer should be `0.66913060635885821382627333068678` by calculator.

But I use netbean to run Java code to calculate eh
`-0.9165215479156338`

```
 time = Math.sin(42.0);

System.out.println(time);
```

Why?

Comment: Tip: if you find yourself writing "X doesn't work in Java" - particularly if it's something so fundamental - you should probably think "I'm using X wrongly" instead. [Look at the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin(double)), and find out what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you're calculating the sine of 42 `radians`.

Try converting to radians first:

```
time = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(42.0));
```

Answer (score 1):

As per the java doc of the method.

> Parameters:
>
> - a - an angle, in radians.
>
> Returns:
>
> the sine of the argument.

The values you see is for sin of 42 radians not for sin of 42 degrees